# Botón que hace cálculos desde los inputs de un form pero no funciona si se hacen cambios en los campos del form, a no ser que actualices la página

Tags: jquery, formularios, localhost, calculo

Salud y saludos.
Rehago mi pregunta, con el código y sin github (no doy una).
Al tema.
Tengo una web con un formulario en el que se introducen las cantidades de cada producto que le corresponden a cada ONG. **Siempre en modo local**, no será necesaria conexión a internet.
Ese formulario tiene un botón que al pulsarlo hace los cálculos necesarios para distribuir los productos en palets vacíos y almacenarlos en estanterías.
El problema es que cuando introduzco los valores de los inputs por primera vez y le doy al botón de los cálculos, lo hace "perfectamente".
Pero si cambio algún valor de los inputs y le doy al botón de calcular no rehace los cálculos, los duplica. Si cambio algún valor de los input, recargo la página en el navegador y le doy al botón de calcular, lo hace "perfectamente".
En resumen: que cada vez que cambio un valor en los inputs me veo obligado a recargar la página.
He probado a poner un "location.reload()" lo primero al hacer el click en el botón calcular. Pero parece que hace los cálculos pero no me da tiempo a verlos. Es un instante.
He reducido los productos a 3 para economizar el código que pongo. No pongo los estilos pues creo no es necesario.

Intento poner todo junto, sin estilos, y espero hacerlo bien porque no doy una.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //palets iniciales de Europa, nombre, filas, unidadesxfilas, total unidades, altura caja, resistencia
    //IMPORTANTE. Si varían los productos, tanto en cantidad como en dimensiones, aqui es donde hay que hacer los cambios
    var p1 = ["aceite", 5, 11, 55, 28.5, 1];
    var p2 = ["alubias", 7, 12, 84, 17.5, 1];
    var p3 = ["arroz p", 8, 10, 80, 16.5, 7];
    //la altura de un palet vacío
    var alt_base = 15;
    //para poner entregado en palets completos
    var entregado = '<div class="paentregado"><div class="entregado"><p>ENTREGADO</p><div class="cuadrado"></div></div></div>';
    //para poner hecho y verificado
    var hecho = '<div class="pacheques"><div class="cheque1"><p>HECHO</p><div class="cuadrado"></div></div><div class="cheque2"><p>VERIFICADO</p><div class="cuadrado"></div></div></div>';
    var total_palets = 0;

    $('#calc_palets').on('click', function(){
        //++ SE AÑADEN al array PALETS COMP, UNID QUE QUEDAN, FILAS SUELTAS AL ALZA, ALTURA FILAS SUELTAS, unidades asignadas, (si el palet incompleto cabe en la estantería)
        anadir_calculos(p1, '#unidadesp1');
        anadir_calculos(p2, '#unidadesp2');
        anadir_calculos(p3, '#unidadesp3');
    //++++++++++++ PONE LOS PALETS COMPLETOS EN HTML ++++++++++
        palets_completos(p1);
        palets_completos(p2);
        palets_completos(p3);
        //+++++++++++++++  PALETS INCOMPLETOS SABER SI CABEN EN ESTANTERIAS (excepciones) +++++++++++++++
        //---------- los condicionales dependen las alturas de cada producto
        //aceite
        if(p1[9]>=142.5){
            $('#palets_incompletos').append("<div class='incompletos'><div><p><span class='palet_prod'>"+p1[0]+"</span>. "+p1[7]+" unidades. SI cabe en la estantería.</p></div>"+hecho+"</div");
            p1[7]=0;
            p1[9]=0;
            ++total_palets
        }
        //se crea EL SUPER array de productos
        var todos_prod = [];
        todos_prod.push(p1,p2,p3);
        //+++++++++++++++++++++++ BARRIDO 2X2 ++++++++++++++++++++
        for(var i=0;i<todos_prod.length;i++){
            var combi2x2 = 0; var mayor_combi = 0; var prod2 = 0;
            if(todos_prod[i][9]!=0){
                var alt_p1=todos_prod[i][9];
                for(var j=i+1;j<todos_prod.length;j++){
                    if(todos_prod[j][9]!=0){
                        var alt_p2 = todos_prod[j][9];
                        combi2x2 = alt_p1 + alt_p2 + alt_base;
                        if(combi2x2>=140 && combi2x2<=170){
                            if(combi2x2>mayor_combi){
                                mayor_combi = combi2x2;
                                prod2 = j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(mayor_combi!=0){
                $(".bloquelistado").append("<div><div><p><span>"+todos_prod[i][5]+" - "+todos_prod[i][0]+"</span>. "+todos_prod[i][7]+" Unidades. "+todos_prod[i][11]+" filas del palet original y "+todos_prod[i][12]+" cajas del palet original.</p>"+"<p><span>"+todos_prod[prod2][5]+" - "+todos_prod[prod2][0]+"</span>. "+todos_prod[prod2][7]+" Unidades. "+todos_prod[prod2][11]+" filas del palet original y "+todos_prod[prod2][12]+" cajas del palet original.</p>"+"<p><span class='altura'>Altura total: "+mayor_combi+"</span></p></div>"+hecho+"</div>");
                todos_prod[i][9]=0;
                todos_prod[prod2][9]=0;
                ++total_palets;
            }
        }//fin barrido 2x2
        //pone los productos sobrantes
        var fila_sobra; var caja_sobra; var altura_sobrantes = 0; var palets_sobrantes = 0;
        for(i=0;i<todos_prod.length;i++){
            if(todos_prod[i][9]!=0){
                //++no_hay;
                fila_sobra = todos_prod[i][11];
                caja_sobra = todos_prod[i][7]%todos_prod[i][2];
                $('#nocombi').append("<div class='sobras'><div><p><span>"+todos_prod[i][5]+" - "+todos_prod[i][0]+"</span>. "+fila_sobra+" filas del palet original y "+caja_sobra+" cajas del palet original. Altura: "+todos_prod[i][9]+".</p></div>"+hecho+"</div>");
                altura_sobrantes = altura_sobrantes + todos_prod[i][9];
            }
        }
        if(altura_sobrantes!=0){
            $('#nocombi').append("<p><span class='altura'>ALTURA TOTAL: </span>"+altura_sobrantes);
            if(altura_sobrantes < 155){
                ++total_palets;
            }else{
                palets_sobrantes = Math.ceil(altura_sobrantes/155);
                total_palets = total_palets + palets_sobrantes;
            }
        }
        $('.total_palets').append("<h3>TOTAL PALETS: "+total_palets);
    });
    
function anadir_calculos(rp1, id_prod){//anadir es añadir
    //coge las unidades del input
    var unidades = parseFloat($(id_prod).val());
    //añade los posibles palets completos
    var palets = parseInt(unidades/rp1[3]);
    rp1.push(palets);
    //añade las cajas sueltas
    var sueltas = unidades%rp1[3];
    rp1.push(sueltas);
    //añade las filas al alza
    var filas = Math.ceil(sueltas/rp1[2]);
    rp1.push(filas);
    //añade la alturas de las cajas al alza
    var alt_sueltas = filas*rp1[4];
    rp1.push(alt_sueltas);
    //añade las unidades otorgadas, posición 10
    rp1.push(unidades);
    //pone las filas no al alza, posición 11
    rp1.push(parseInt(sueltas/rp1[2]));
    //pone las cajas fuera de fila, posicion 12
    rp1.push(unidades%rp1[2]);
}
function palets_completos(rp1){
    var palets = rp1[6];
    if(palets!=0){
        $('#palets_iniciales').append("<div class='palets_iniciales'><p><span class='palet_prod'>"+rp1[0]+"</span>: "+palets+"</p>"+entregado+"</div>");
        ++total_palets;
    }
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CalcPalet</title>
<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

<meta name="description" content=""><!--160 caracteres máximo, descripción del contenido la página, el txt que se ve debajo del nombre -->
<meta name="keywords" content="palabra clave 1, palabra clave 2, palabra clave 3">
<meta name="author" content="rizos">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="guiones.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Introducción de datos DIMENSIONES de los productos AQUÍ EN HTML. Cuando llegan de Europa-->
    <div id="datos">
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <label>Entidad o ONG: </label>
            <input class="ong" id="ong" type="text" size="80"><br>
            <label>Población: </label>
            <input class="ong" id="poble" type="text" size="50">
            <label> Fecha: </label>
            <input class="ong" id="fecha" type="date" size="50">
            <p>Introducir las unidades de cada producto asignadas a la ONG (en centímetros)</p>
            <div class="paunidades">
                <label>ACEITE </label><input id="unidadesp1" class="unidades" type="number" size="6" value="0">
                <label>ALUBIAS </label><input id="unidadesp2" class="unidades" type="number" size="6" value="0">
                <label>ARROZ P </label><input id="unidadesp3" class="unidades" type="number" size="6" value="0">
            </div>
            <div class="paboton">
                <button type="button" id="calc_palets" name="calc_palets">CALCULAR</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="palets_iniciales">
        <h3>PALETS COMPLETOS</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="palets_incompletos">
        <h3>PALETS INCOMPLETOS<span>. Un sólo producto, pero no cabe nada más</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="listados">
        <h3>COMBINACIONES DE PRODUCTOS<span>. Poner primero los productos más resistentes.</span></h3>
        <div class="bloquelistado">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="restos listados">
        <h3>PRODUCTOS SUELTOS<span>. Combinar por alturas</span></h3>
        <div id="nocombi">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total_palets">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por adelantado y cuidaos mucho.

Comment: No pongas un enlace a github. Incluye tu código como parte de la pregunta, idealmente prepara un [mcve]. No hace falta que publiques nuevas preguntas, puedes editar esta pregunta para incluirlo. Para aprender como funciona StackOverflow date una vuelta por el [tour] y por [ask].

Comment: Debes poner el codigo que se relaciona con tu problema

Comment: Espero haberlo hecho bien, esta vez

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado mis problemas. Eran dos fallos.

**Problema 1** (necesidad de refrescar la página si cambiaba algo en el formulario):

- lo que hacía era crear un array, al inicio de $document.ready, para cada producto con sus datos básicos (altura, unidades por fila, etc)
- luego al hacer click en "calcular", con el ánimo de preservar los datos básicos iniciales, creaba otro array por producto (y aquí estaba el fallo) igual al original. Es decir, si los datos básicos del producto 1 era el array "po1" hacía "var p1=po1". Y así con el resto de productos.
- luego hacía las posibles combinaciones por alturas y si 2 productos combinaban, ponía sus alturas a 0 para que ya no entraran otra vez en los cálculos de más combinaciones de productos
- ¿qué ocurría?
- que si ponía la altura del array del producto para los cálculos "p1" a 0, también se ponía a 0 la altura del array original "po1"
- si cambiaba algún valor de un producto en el formulario y volvía a darle al botón de calcular, dado que los productos que combinaban tenían altura=0 ya no entraban en los cálculos
  CONCLUSIÓN: no es lo mismo hacer "var p1=p01" que "var p1=po1.slice(x, y)". Porque digamos que slice no "vincula" los valores del array original y el del "destino".
  Error de novato.

**Problema 2** (al darle al botón de calcular por segunda vez se repetían las combinaciones entre productos):

- lo que hacía era al combinar dos o más productos, según alturas, mediante un "append" los ponía en su div correspondiente
- al darle por segunda vez a calcular, ya estaban ahí y volvían a repetirse
- lo solucioné con un "remove" en los divs correspondientes
  CONCLUSIÓN: si añades algo en el DOM y necesitas "recalcular" lo hecho, no se te olvide eliminarlo antes.
  Error de novato.

Espero que mi experiencia os sirva de ayuda.
Gracias por todo y cuidaos mucho.